# CKEditor styles list styling

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, drupal-8

I have succesfully defined custom styles within ckEditor. I have a custom style for  header. The styling of these styles are also shown in de actual styles list. 
Is it possible to give all the styles shown in the style list the same style so they are readable?if yes, how can i style the styles list?

[Image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxLE9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find proper way to disable it, but you can changes source of style list  ( check this https://ckeditor.com/addon/stylescombo  ), which contain this part of code

```
panel: {
css: [ CKEDITOR.skin.getPath( 'editor' ) ].concat( config.contentsCss ),
multiSelect: true,
attributes: { 'aria-label': lang.panelTitle }
},
```

If you remove(or modify) css property it will affect styling in combobox